# How to remove a field of an array's nested object that has an empty string value using mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So far, after i tried, i came up with solution where i am able to remove the whole object inside of the array if that object has field with empty value. That does not work in my case. I only need to remove the field and keep rest of the object. In this case, "Comment" field is the one having empty values occasionally. Thanks in advance!

Structure:

```json
someArray: [
    {
      field1:"value",
      field2:"value",
      Comment:"",
      Answer:"",
},
    {
      field1:"value",
      field2:"value",
      Comment:"",
      Answer:"",

}]
```

Code:

```json
        $project: {
          someArray: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$someArray", as: "array",
              cond: { $ne: [ "$$array.Comment", ""]}}}}
```

Comment: Instead of `$filter` try using the `$map` operator. And, use `$$REMOVE` system variable to delete a field.

Comment: Do you want to update the document permanently or it is specific to a read operation?

Comment: I have tried, but it is removing the whole object if "Comment": "". Specific to read operation. Thank you!

Comment: if i use $map instead  of $filter cond becomes unrecognized parameter

Comment: @prasad_ I think with `$$REMOVE` you an remove only entire fields but not single elements from an array.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit OP is asking a question about removing a field conditionally.

Comment: @prasad_ yes, but I still have no clue how you would implements this with `$$REMOVE`. Maybe `$unwind -> $$REMOVE (or $unset) -> $group` would be an approach.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You are correct that the `$$REMOVE` didn''t work in this case. But,  I have posted a solution which uses `$map` operator - and you might be interested in looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$map` to loop over the array elements.For each array element where comment is not an empty string, return whole element, otherwise return the document excluding comment field. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      someArray: {
        $map: {
          input: "$someArray",
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "",
                  "$$element.Comment"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                field1: "$$element.field1",
                field2: "$$element.field2"
              },
              else: "$$element"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

Here, is the working [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CRSWzI_C_wY).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution where an array's nested object can have multiple fields and these need not be referred in the aggregation. Removes the nested object's field with value as an empty string (`""`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
  $set: { 
      someArray: { 
          $map: { 
              input: '$someArray', 
              as: 'e',
              in: {
                  $let: {
                      vars: {
                          temp_var: { 
                              $filter: { 
                                  input: { $objectToArray: '$$e' }, 
                                  cond: { $ne: [ '', '$$this.v' ] }, 
                              }
                           }
                      },
                      in: {
                          $arrayToObject: '$$temp_var'
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
},
])
```

Comment: Maybe better `cond: {$not: {$and: [ {$eq: ["$$this.k", "Comment"]}, {$eq: ["$$this.v", ""]} ]}}`

Comment: Maybe, if your data has other fields with empty values. Finally, its a matter of the requirement.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit To check for just one field only (in this case, `Comment`), use this for the cond: `$or: [ { $ne: [ 'Comment', '$$this.k' ] },  { $and: [ { $eq: [ 'Comment', '$$this.k' ] }, { $ne: [ '', '$$this.v' ] } ] } ]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Charchit Kapoor works only if your array has exactly

```
{
  field1: ...
  field2: ...
  Comment:""
}
```

But it does not work for arbitrary fields. I was looking for more generic solution, my first idea was this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      "$project": {
         someArray: {
            $map: {
               input: "$someArray",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$this.Comment", ""] },
                     then: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { Comment: "$$REMOVE" }] },
                     else: "$$this"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

but it does not work.

I ended on this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      "$project": {
         someArray: {
            $map: {
               input: "$someArray",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["", "$$this.Comment"] },
                     then: {
                        $arrayToObject: {
                           $filter: {
                              input: {
                                 $map: {
                                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$this" },
                                    as: "element",
                                    in: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$element.k", "Comment"] }, null, "$$element"] }
                                 }
                              },
                              as: "filter",
                              cond: "$$filter" // removes null's from array 
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     else: "$$this"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yDIbwHay-be)